# Variable length array/ data structure in C++

Tags: c++

I want to implement an algorithm in `C++` somewhat similar to this, which is in `MATLAB`

```
A = [1 3 4 2 5 7 8 6];

N = length(A);

v_arr = []

for i=1:1:N
    if somefunction(A(i))
            v_arr =[ v_arr ,i];
    else someOtherfunction(A(i))
            v_arr =[ v_arr ,i];
    end
 end
```

Basically I want to collect the indices of the array `A` which satisfies some conditions. What is the most efficient way to store these indices in `C++` while processing in the loop as in the `v_arr` in above example.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and reserve size of `A` (which is the upper boundary for number of matches). (And, please, don't forget that indices of arrays start with 0 in C++.)

Comment: @Scheff The above example is in MATLAB which starts at index 1.

Comment: `std::vector` is one of the most basic tools for C++ especially concerning dynamic arrays. As you seemed not to be aware of this, I believed the hint with 0 index couldn't hurt... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below a somehow 1 to 1 solution in CPP.

Please note: I guess that nobody would do it like that in C++. Most probably, other language constructs would be used.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Example function 1. Even numbers
bool someFunction(const int i) {
    return (i%2 == 0);
}

// Exampel function 2. Dividable by 3
bool someOtherFunction(const int i) {
    return (i%3 == 0);
}

int main() {

    // Define Vector and initialize some values
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6};

    // Get size of vector.The number of elements int he vector
    const size_t N = A.size();

    // Define next dynamic vector (initially empty) for indices
    std::vector<size_t> v_arr{};

    // Loop over all elements from initial data vector
    for (size_t i=0U; i<N; ++i) {

        // Check, if condition 1 is fullfilled
        if (someFunction(A[i])) {

            // Add index to destination  vector
            v_arr.push_back(i);
        }
        // Check, if condition 2 is fullfilled
        else if (someOtherFunction(A[i])) {
            // Add index to destination  vector
            v_arr.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    // SHow result
    for (const int index : v_arr) std::cout << index << " ";
    std::cout <<"\n\n"  ;

    return 0;
}
```